# linked list c++ code error

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am new to C++. I have written a C++ code for linked list. I get a error message after running the code in eclipse saying "linkedlist.exe stopped working". Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong. In the code i create a linked list and insert few values in it. I then wrote a statement to print the elements.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* P;
};
Node* H;
void Insert(int data)
{
    Node* temp=new Node();
    temp->data=data;
    temp->P=NULL;
    Node* temp1=H;
    while(temp1->P!=NULL)
    {
        temp1=temp1->P;
    }
    temp1->P=temp;
}
int main()
{
    cout<<"linked list"<<endl;
    Insert(1);
    Insert(2);
    Insert(3);
    Node* Print=H;
    while(Print!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<Print->data<<endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: `H` is uninitialized. It doesn't have a `P` member you can use.

Comment: Have you tried the debugger? Why not try compiling with all the warnings on

Comment: thanks. I added H=temp before Node* temp1=H; in Insert function, and H=NULL initially in main. The error disappeared. the values won't print though :(

Comment: I changed my code to this..it still is not printing

Comment: Don't keep changing your code and saying "it's still not working". *Simplify.* Try constructing one node with a value, then printing the value of that node. Once you have that working perfectly, construct a second node and link it using the simplest code you can write for the task -- *not* a general `Insert` function -- and printing both values. Once you have that working perfectly, try writing the `Insert` function. Once you have that working perfectly... you get the idea.

Comment: `I am new to C++. I have written a C++ code for linked list.`  If you're new to C++, why are you attempting to write a class that can only be written correctly by intermediate/advanced C++ programmers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Initialize H.
Node* H = NULL;

void Insert(int data)
{
    Node* temp=new Node();
    temp->data=data;
    temp->P=NULL;

    // If there is nothing in the list, make the new Node the head.
    if ( H == NULL )
    {
       H = temp;
    }
    else
    {
       Node* temp1=H;
       while(temp1->P!=NULL)
       {
          temp1=temp1->P;
       }
       temp1->P=temp;
    }
}
```

**Update**

The `while` lop for printing the list needs to be:

```
while(Print!=NULL)
{
    cout<<Print->data<<endl;
    Print = Print->P; // Missing in your code.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The error disappeared. I did this but i still cannot get the values to print on screen... :(

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, give better names to variables. For example,  `Node* P` doesn't make sense, you can name it as `next, prev` or whatever you want making you and other people understand. You can also take a look at [naming conventions](http://geosoft.no/development/cppstyle.html)

Secondly, I don't think `insert` works. Are you trying to insert to first, or end or a position. I would write something like that:

```
void insert(int val, int pos){
     Node newNode = null;
     newNode -> data = val;
     Node temp = H;
     if(pos<0){
         H = newNode;
         H->P = temp;
     }
     else{
         for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++){
              if(temp->P != null)
                   temp = temp->P
              else break;
         }
         //I found the position of the element you supposed to insert
         //You insert the element properly.
         //Make sure that you link the next element to newNode;
     }
}
```

You can learn insertion from [this page](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Singly-linked_list/Insertion)

Finally, your print out always check the first element. `If Print->data != null`, you would always print the first element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the help. I wrote the following and it worked just fine. This is a linked list code to insert data value at the end of list.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
Node* Head;
void Insert(int data)
{
    Node* temp=new Node();
    temp->data=data;
    temp->next=NULL;
    if(Head==NULL)
    {
        Head=temp;
        return;
    }
    Node* temp1=Head;
    while(temp1->next!=NULL)
    {
        temp1=temp1->next;
    }
    temp1->next=temp;

}
int main()
{
    Head=NULL;
    cout<<"linked list"<<endl;
    Insert(1);
    Insert(2);
    Insert(3);
    Node* Print=Head;
    while(Print!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"data=" <<Print->data<<endl;
        Print=Print->next;
    }

}
```